# all button function whenever click in php

Tags: java, php, html, mysqli

I create one page where it fetch all data from register page. I put button for all that page. I have a problem once i click one button all button was change to request sent. I dont know how it happen.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myid'];

$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','learning_malaysia');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutor_register INNER JOIN tutorskill ON tutor_register.register_ID = tutorskill.register_ID ORDER BY 
tutor_register.register_ID='".$_SESSION['myid']."'desc";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
?>

<html>
<title>friend</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{      

      $register_ID=$row["register_ID"];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $profile = $row['profile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $address=$row['address'];
        $gender=$row['gender'];
         $main_subject=$row["main_subject"];
         $subject_add=$row["subject_add"];
        $rate_main=$row["rate_main"];
        $rate_add=$row["rate_add"];
        $qualification=$row["qualification"];?>
        <table><form method="post">
        <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td height="230"><img src='<?php echo $profile;?>'width="200" height="200"/>&nbsp;</td><td><td></td></td>
        <td class="data" width="800"><strong>Username:</strong>  <?php echo $username;?></br>
        <strong>Address:</strong>  <?php echo $address;?></br>
        <strong>Gender:</strong><?php echo $gender;?></br>
         <strong>Main Subject:</strong><?php echo $main_subject  ;?></br>
         <strong>Subject Added: </strong><?php echo $subject_add;?></br>
         <strong>Main Subject Rate:</strong> <?php echo $rate_main;?></br>
        <strong> Added Subject Rate:</strong><?php echo $rate_add; ?></br>
         <strong>Qualification:</strong> <?php echo $qualification; ?></td>
           <?php 
         if($register_ID == $_SESSION['myid']){
                ?>
                <td><label>Your Profile</label></td>
                <?php
            } else {

                    ?>

                 <form method="post">
                 <td><button class='friendBtn unfriend'  name="" data-type="unfriend">Unfriend</button>
                 <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />  
                 <input type="submit" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php 
                     if($_SESSION['status'] == 'yes'){ 
                     echo 'Request Sent';
                     }
                     else { 
                     echo 'Addfriend';}
                     ?>" data-uid=<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>/></td> </form>     
</td> 
<?php
            }
            }
?>
 </tr>
</div>
</table>
 </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']) ) {
$user_id = $_SESSION['myid'];
$friend_id = $_POST['id'];
$sql="INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','yes','$friend_id') ";

            if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                          $_SESSION['status']="yes";
                          $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
            } else {}
                              }
                }


?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and properly format your postings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See condition `$row['register_ID']==$_SESSION['id']` added below. This will solve your problem.

```
<form method="post">
   <td><button class='friendBtn unfriend'  name="" data-type="unfriend">Unfriend</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />  
      <input type="submit" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php 
         if($_SESSION['status'] == 'yes' && $row['register_ID']==$_SESSION['id']){ 
            echo 'Request Sent';
         }
         else { 
            echo 'Addfriend';}
         ?>" data-uid=<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>/>
   </td>
</form>
```